# All `npm install` in docker gets corrupted

Tags: docker, npm, lerna

All docker images I try to create gets corrupted at the point of running `npm install`.

Two of those images gave errors like this :

```
[stage-1 4/5] RUN npm install -g pm2 --loglevel warn
       → npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '..."2.3.7","dependencies'
```

And then this

```
   [src  4/20] RUN npm install lerna --global
       → npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '.../changed","version":"'
```

While the others just get stuck while installing anything related to lerna.

My colleagues don't have this issues, so it does not make any sense to change anything in the build steps.

I am quite confused about this.

Note: I have ran `docker system prune -a` to remove all caches so I can start afresh but the issues lingers all the same.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try setting registry?

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```